# Loop through characters in a string

Tags: java, string, for-loop, replace, char

How would I go about looping though each character in a string, then setting that character to something else? Unless of course there is a better way to do what I am trying to do. I am creating a Bukkit plugin which will change words in a chat message based on what it contains. Here is what I have so far:

```
for (String word : e.getMessage().split(" ") {
    if (wordList.contains(word)) {
        e.setMessage(e.getMessage.replaceAll(word, "*");
    }
}
```

However, I want to be able to set each character in the word, instead of setting the entire word. I tried something like this, but my IDE didn't like it. Note that this is building off of the above code and is within the check if the wordList contains the word.

```
for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
    // there are no available methods for editing the char c
}
```

It would be appreciated if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class and a regular expression that matches each character to replace each.

```
ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
wordList.add("foo");
wordList.add("carrots");

String message = "The foo bar message about carrots";

// use this class to match each character with the regex dot
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".", Pattern.DOTALL);
// use to create the new message from the words (some replaced with asterisk)
StringBuffer newMessage = new StringBuffer();
// loop through each word
for (String word : message.split(" ") ){
    // if it is in your list....
    if (wordList.contains(word)) {
        // add it to newMessage, but replaced by asterisk.
        newMessage.append(p.matcher(word).replaceAll("*"));
    } else {
        // add the unmodified word
        newMessage.append(word);
    }
    // add a space before we loop to the next word
    newMessage.append(" ");
}
// set the new message string with some words replaced
message = newMessage.toString().trim();
System.out.println(message);
```

Will output the following text when run:

> The foo bar message about carrots
>
> The *** bar message about *******

**UPDATE - example code to replace banned words with asterisk**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Your input string
    String message = "The foo bar message about carrots. Carrots suck so do parrots. Parrotsucker is partially masked. Carrots was already replaced.";
    System.out.println(message);
    
    // An array of words you want to mask
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordList.add("foo");
    wordList.add("carrots");
    wordList.add("parrots");
    
    // Create a regex to match the banned words.... in this case it will be "foo|carrots|parrots", case insensitive
    String regex = Arrays.toString(wordList.toArray());
    regex = regex.substring(1, regex.length()-1).replaceAll(", ", "|");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    System.out.println("Regex: " + p);
    
    // Keep track of the asterisks strings by length so we don't generate more than once
    Map<Integer, String> maskMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    // Since we use replaceAll we might get a match more than once, so we can track and skip once that have already been handled
    Vector<String> replaced = new Vector<String>();
    // Find a list of banned words in the input message
    Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
    // Loop over each of the matches
    while (m.find()){
        // Get the text of each match
        String match = m.group();
        // Have we already replaced it in the message?
        if ( !replaced.contains(match) ){
            // This is what we will replace it with
            String mask = null;
            // See if we have a string the same length as the current match
            if ( maskMap.containsKey(match.length())) {
                // If so, get it out of the map.
                mask = maskMap.get(match.length());
                System.out.println("Got mask from maskMap: " + mask);
            } else {
                // No mask, so generate one and save it in the Map
                StringBuffer maskBuffer = new StringBuffer("*");
                while ( maskBuffer.length() < match.length() ){
                    maskBuffer.append("*");
                }
                mask = maskBuffer.toString();
                maskMap.put(mask.length(), mask);
                System.out.println("Generated new entry for maskMap: " + mask);
            }
            // Replace the matched banned word with the correct mask
            message = message.replaceAll(match, mask);
            // Track that we already replaced this word
            replaced.add(match);
            System.out.println((new StringBuffer("   Replaced '").append(match).append("' with '").append(mask).append("'")).toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Aready replaced: " + match);
        }
    }
    
    // The message with banned words masked.
    System.out.println(message);
    
    System.exit(0);
    
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
The foo bar message about carrots. Carrots suck so do parrots. Parrotsucker is partially masked. Carrots was already replaced.
Regex: foo|carrots|parrots
Generated new entry for maskMap: ***
   Replaced 'foo' with '***'
Generated new entry for maskMap: *******
   Replaced 'carrots' with '*******'
Got mask from maskMap: *******
   Replaced 'Carrots' with '*******'
Got mask from maskMap: *******
   Replaced 'parrots' with '*******'
Got mask from maskMap: *******
   Replaced 'Parrots' with '*******'
Aready replaced: Carrots
The *** bar message about *******. ******* suck so do *******. *******ucker is partially masked. ******* was already replaced.
```

Comment: I have never used nor heard of the Pattern class, what exactly does it do? And what does the code you provided do? I would like to understand what I put in my code instead of just copy-pasting.

Comment: From a high level there isn't much more than is in the answer - the Pattern class is used to match regular expressions against strings. In this case you use a dot (.) to match all characters, and then replace each occurrence with an asterisk. Looking again however you code has other bugs as well, I will update my answer.

Comment: @RoboticPlayer My answer is updated along with some sample out. Keep in mind that this won't work if there is a punctuation mark at the end since you are only splitting on spaces - you should probably remove the punctuation first since "foo" != "foo."

Comment: Ok, it works. However, whenever a player chats, it puts the message at the end. This might not make sense, so I will explain. So if I type "hello" in chat, it prints as hello. If I then type "test", it will print "hello test". I tried to fix this by setting my editedMessage field (the equivalent of your newMessage field) to null, but now it throws an NPE whenever I chat (for a second time). It will only work once, then the server has to be reloaded. Here is what I have: http://pastebin.com/uyJx9ZKv

Comment: @RoboticPlayer you should either move `StringBuffer editedMessage = new StringBuffer();` to just above your `for` loop so that it has a local scope instead of global, or call `editedMessage.setLength(0)` just above the `for` loop to drop the current contents - you have to reinitialize it or it will still have the previous input.

Comment: The NPE is because you set the global `StringBuffer editedMessage` to `null`, so the next time it calls `append()` on it, you get the exception.

Comment: Ok, I just didn't know how to clear a StringBuffer. I have changed it a little bit, is it possible to only blank out the specified word if there are other things attached to it? http://pastebin.com/ihPLcRUN Edit: Let's say that "foo" is in my list of words. If I type "foo", it prints "***", which is good. But if someone types "foo[other characters]" it will change the entire thing to asterisks. Is it possible to only change the word in the list? So if I type "foo1" it will say "***1" instead of "****".

Comment: That's really a different question, but since I haven't played around with java in a while see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot modified any character directly in String because String is immutable.

Alternatively, you can create a new string after merging your desired characters.

Take a look at this code:

```
        String word = "Look";
        String modifiedWord = word.substring(0,1) + "***" + word.substring(word.length()-1);
        System.out.println(modifiedWord);
```

You can try this if you need to set symbols only within your matched string body not at the begin and end of the string.

```
Output: L***k
```

Your code can be modified as follows:

```
   String modifiedWord = null;
    for (String word : e.getMessage().split(" ") {
        if (wordList.contains(word)) {
            modifiedWord = word.substring(0,1) + "***" + word.substring(word.length()-1);
            e.setMessage(e.getMessage.replaceAll(word, modifiedWord);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

That code makes you print change every character for * until don't get a space, so if your word is *banana* he will print ********

```
char[] c= word.toCharArray();

    String newString ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i] != ' ' ) newString += "*";
    }
    System.out.println(newString);
```

**EDIT**

if you also want change a setence, change to these

```
String word = "foo  woord";
    char[] c= word.toCharArray();

    String newString ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i] != ' ' ) newString += "*";
            else newString += " ";
    }
    System.out.println(newString);
```

**Answer:** ****  ******

Hope i resolve your problem

Comment: That is just going to replace "test" with "\*", the question is asking how to arrive at "\*\*\*\*" for "test" but "***" for "foo".

Comment: You should also use a `StringBuffer` or the like to concatenate strings, using `+=` will create lots of junk objects for the GC to clean up.

Comment: @RoboticPlayer, check my answer please!